# Adobe AIR - Option to not create a shortcut when installing an AIR application

Tags: apache-flex, air, startmenu

Hello Stackoverflow community,

Does anyone know if there is an option to not create a shortcut to an AIR application after its installation?

Currently, all I have found is an option to choose the location of the application shortcut from within the start menu (in the application descriptor file, using the programMenuFolder option)

Thanks,
Mauricio

Answer (score 1):

Using installers.

See: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/distributing_air_in_enterprise_02.html